# apache2 url cropped when alias used

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki, mod-alias

I setup my mediawiki server with apache2.

I use alias to redirect my url to the right location: (/etc/apche2/conf-enabled/mediawiki.conf)

```
Alias /wiki /var/lib/mediawiki
<Directory /var/lib/mediawiki/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
            Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.3>
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

Problem is that when I access the wiki, it crops my url somehow, which causes issues:

**durban.ucl.tch.edu/wiki** becomes **durban/wiki**

Why would the alias change the url?
How can I keep the full url with the alias?

Best,
Nicolas

Comment: It's nothing in this part of the config. It's possible that MediaWiki has a notion of what the outwards name is, so it can put it in links, and that you need to configure that separately. Or maybe it tries to guess -- can you give us the output of `hostname -f`? It should be `durban.ucl.tch.edu`, I'd guess.

Comment: yes, hostname -f works as expected (it returns durban.ucl.tch.edu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mediawiki docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php#Server_name) suggests that you can set the `$wgServer` variable in the mediawiki config like this:

```
$wgServer = 'http://durban.ucl.tch.edu';
```

which you may or may not consider a workaround.

Comment: That fixed it! (configuration file: /usr/share/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php)

Comment: Best fix is actually just to get rid of this variable. I had it misconfigured.